# #1046 - No database selected

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

Can you please explain why I get this error?? It happened when I tried to import my database which I created in an earlier xampp to the newer xampp. Here's the error code:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 2.8.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
-- 
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Mar 06, 2014 at 11:21 AM
-- Server version: 5.0.21
-- PHP Version: 5.1.4
-- 
-- Database: `dev_alumni`
-- 

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `alm_block_user`
-- 
CREATE TABLE `alm_block_user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_ref_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` text collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
```

MySQL said:

```
#1046 - No database selected
```

Comment: It is only table you are trying to create.
First select a database
Then try it.

Comment: Try `USE`command http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a database before importing.

Answer (score 5):

create a database `dev_alumni` using your phpmyadmin,

Select that database and then Import

Answer (score 1):

You must indicate which database to use unless there is a active sesssion. You could indicate that in the syntax without use.

If the database doesnt exists execute this first.

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS dev_alumni;

CREATE TABLE dev_alumni.`alm_block_user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_ref_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` text collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
```